# Two-phase simplex method: Artificial variable's row has only zero coefficients

Tags: linear-programming, two-phase-simplex

I am stuck with the simplex algorithm.

I am trying to create the initial solution (where all variables are nonnegative).

My artificial variable is in the basis, and its value is 0. So I would like to pivot it out (and remove the column where it gets)

However, all coefficients in its row are either zero, or the corresponding coefficient of the objective function is negative.

What can I do in such situation?

Here are some pictures from Excel:

The original LP:

[image: Original LP]

The auxiliary LP to find a nonnegative solution for the original:
[image]

And the problem, where after many steps I cannot take the artificial variable (x0) out of the basis even though its value is 0:

[image]

Comment: You can still pivot on the column with a negative coefficient in the objective.  Because the value of the artificial variable in the current basic solution is zero, the value of the objective for the new basic solution will remain at zero, and it will be feasible for the original problem.

Comment: But the objective function in the first phase is to minimize the value of x0, to make the solution feasible. If this objective value changes, then the basis solution becomes infeasible, doesn't it?

Comment: I assumed the "objective function" you mentioned in your question *was* that of phase one.  My point was that if the artificial basic variable has a value of zero, then the value of the objective function *shouldn't* change when you eliminate that variable from the set of basic variables, *regardless* of what sign the coefficient of the new basic variable (whose value should also be zero) had in the objective function.  However, it's quite possible there's something I'm not understanding, so it would be helpful if you could post the precise details of the problem.

Comment: It looks to me that in your final tableau you could swap any of the variables $\ x_{44}, x_{40}, x_{25},$ or $\ x_{29}\ $ into the basis to replace $\ x_0\ $, by pivoting on the last row and the appropriate column.  After you do this, however, the (now non-basic) variable $\ x_0\ $ will have a negative coefficient in the objective function and in the rows of the basic variables $\ x_{41}, x_{42},$ and $\ x_{43}\ $.

Comment: That should not be possible, however, because it would mean that there would be a *positive* value of $\ x_0\ $ that would both *decrease* the (auxiliary) objective function to a negative value and still maintain feasibility.  It therefore suggests to me either that there must be something wrong with your setup, or an arithmetical error has occurred in your pivot operations.